# React JS Button handle switch from "On" to "Off"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class

How to modify the component so that you can properly toggle the button to switch between an "**ON**" state and an "**OFF**" state. When the button is on and it is clicked, it turns off and the text within it changes from "**ON**" to "**OFF**" and vice versa.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  
 state = {
   switchButton: "Off"
 }

  handleClick(text) {
    this.setState({switchButton: text})
      }

  
  render() {

    return (
      <button onClick={()=> this.handleClick("On")}>
      {this.state.switchButton}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's best to use a `boolean` for the state and then simply do `setState({ switchButton: !this.state.switchButton } )` + `{this.state.switchButtton ? 'On' : 'Off'}`

Comment: or like that 
  handleClick() {
    if (this.state.switchButton === "Off") {
      this.setState({switchButton: "On"})
    } else {
      this.setState({switchButton: "Off"})
    }
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
export default class App extends Component {

    state = {
        status: false,
        switchButton: "Off"
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState({
            status: !this.state.status,
            switchButton: !this.state.status ? 'ON' : 'OFF'
        })
    }


    render() {

        return (
            <button onClick={()=> this.handleClick()}>
                {this.state.switchButton}
            </button>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. Thank you.

```js
export default class App extends Component {
  
  state = {
    isOn: false,
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(preState => ({ isOn: !preState.isOn }))
  }

  
  render() {
    const { isOn } = this.state;
    
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
      {isOn ? "On" : "Off"}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If this helps you, could you please accept this answer? It will help future visitors to recognize what answer worked for you. Thanks so much.